# JavaScript, regular expression to validate phone numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate phone Number in the format X-XXX-XXX-XXXX

```
    var phone= prompt("Enter phonenumber in the format X-XXX-XXX-XXXX");
    var regEx= /\d-[\ddd\-]{2}\d{4}/; 
    if(regEx.test(phone))
    {document.write("Is valid PhoneNumber "+phone);}
    else{
     var msg= "Chaphert 6 exmaple 2a says <br/>" +phone +" is invalid";
     alert(msg);
    }
```

I could have used `regEx=/\d-\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}`,which will solve my problem but since I have to repeat this `xxx-xxx-`,ie I don't wish to repeat `\d{3}-` twice in the regex, expecting something to replace for \d{3}-\d{3}- with something like, [\d{3}-]{2}. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: how about `^\d(-\d{3}){3}\d$` ?

Comment: What is `[\ddd\-]` supposed to mean? Did you look at this regexp on a regexp testing site? Do you know the difference between `[]` (character sets) and `()` groups? Anyway, your original regexp is much clearer and there's no reason to fiddle with it further.

Comment: Why don't you want to repeat the `\d{3}`? That makes it clear what the underlying structure you are trying to match actually is. It is easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following regex should do what you ask:

```
^\d(?:-\d{3}){3}\d$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/yI3pR3/2)

Comment: This regexp works, but it hides the 1-3-3-4 structure.

Comment: yeah,but what'd be the problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you want a pattern that shows the 1-3-3-4 structure and want to prevent to use

```
'-\d{3}'
```

twice, you could put this part into a group and repeat it twice.

The final pattern would look like this then:

```
'^\d-(\d{3}-){2}\d{4}$'
```

Comment: thanks it worked i was mixing two languages grouping java and javascript

Answer (score 0):

Thanks  for your help i need to replace [] with () for grouping
ie

```
    var phone= prompt("Enter phonenumber in the format X-XXX-XXX-XXXX");
    var regEx= /\d-(\d{3}\-){2}\d{4}/; 
     if(regEx.test(phone))
      {alert("Is valid PhoneNumber "+phone);}
     else{
     var msg= "Entered phone number " +phone +" is invalid";
     alert(msg);
     }
```

solved my problem, it worked as expected